# How do I pass a filestream variable to another method?

Tags: c#, function, methods, overloading, filestream

How do I pass my filestream from openXaml() to timedEvent()

method1

```
    private void openXaml()
    {
        FileStream  fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);       
    }
```

method 2 (Cannot add overloads)

```
private void timedEvent()
{ 
Grid page = (Grid)XamlReader.Load(fs);
}
```

I had the filestream var in method 2, but I kept running into issues because it is a timed event. So now, I need to figure out how to pass the filestream to method 2 from method 1.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's your own code that is calling these two methods you can simply return the filestream from the first method, keep it as variable in the calling code and pass it as a parameter to the second method.

```
private FileStream openXaml()
{
    return new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);       
}

private void timedEvent(FileStream stream)
{ 
    Grid page = (Grid)XamlReader.Load(fs);
}

private void Caller() 
{
   var stream = openXaml();
   timedEvent(stream);

   // or
   timedEvent(openXaml);
}
```

**Edit**

This kind of code will work if :

- Both methods are in the same class.
- You are using the same object through the process.
- You ensure openXaml is called before timedEvent. (I added a null check in case)

  ```
  public class Example 
  { 
     private FileStream _filestream;

     private void openXaml()
     {
        _fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);       
     }

     private void timedEvent()
     { 
        if (_fileStream != null) 
        {
           Grid page = (Grid)XamlReader.Load(_fileStream);
        }
     }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I can't add overloads to timedEvent()

Comment: If you can't touch the method (or you do not control how it's called) but both methods are in the same class, you could use a private field in that class. openXaml would fill the field and timedEvent would use that field.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Something like this:
private FileStream  fs = null;
private void openXaml()
{
   fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);       
}
private void timedEvent()
{ 
 Grid page = (Grid)XamlReader.Load(fs);
}
The scope of fs is throughout the class.

Comment: I edit my answer to add my comment and the one from Gargi D. Chakravarty
.